# С чего начать проект в VBA с использованием Excel?

Tags: файлы, excel, vba

Требуется написать программу на ВБА при использовании которой при выборе студента из таблицы (в строке имя студента а далее его оценки) в новом файле формата PDF был создан список из оценок и названия предметов для этого студента. Подскажите пожалуйста с чего лучше начать.

Comment: с создания списка студентов с оценками

Comment: Списки для студентов имеются уже.

Comment: как вариант, вынести необходимые данные на новую страницу и сохранить ее в нужном формате

Comment: Перво-наперво нужно правильно писать имя программы, в которой собираетесь работать - Excel :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм:

1. Создать список студентов
2. Создать таблицу взаимозависимостей студент->предмет->оценка в любом удобном виде (студенты в столбце, предметы в строку, оценки на пересечении или аналог БД - таблица "студент-предмет-оценка"
3. В зависимости от выбранного студента в установленной нужной форме подтянуть данные по предметам и оценкам (в новую книгу/лист)
4. Сохранить новую книгу/лист как PDF
5. Profit